# filtering MYSQL results with HTML form option selector using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I'm trying to apply a filter for a sql query which displays the mag wheels based on the manufacturer selected.

So far it generates a dropdown list for the html form, and is supposed to pass it back using $_POST and then is applied to the sql query to redisplay the page. I have something similar working but that uses an array and checkboxs instead of the option> box used in this form.

currently It doesn't apply any filter and actually breaks the loop which generates the wheels to be displayed...

```
// Getting manufacturer to create the filter list.
    $filterManu = "SELECT DISTINCT manufacturer FROM wheels";
    $filterManuResult = mysqli_query($db, $filterManu) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($db));

// Applying the filtering
if (isset($_POST['manu'])) {

    $option = $_POST['manu'];
    $featuredsql = "SELECT * FROM wheels WHERE manufacturer = " . $option . " ORDER BY diam";
}

$featured = $db->query($featuredsql);
```

Form that generates the list of manufacturers to select from and submits the post from the form.

```
    <form name="manuFilter" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group"></div>
            <select name="manu">
             <option selected disabled>Select a manufacturer</option>
             <?php while($rowManu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filterManuResult)) : ?>
                <option name="manu" value="<?php echo $rowManu['manufacturer']; ?>"><?php echo $rowManu['manufacturer']; ?></option>
             <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>    

           <div class="form-group"></div>
           <button type="submit" name="filterOptions" value="displayManu" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Apply</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to b updated:

```
    $featuredsql = "SELECT * FROM wheels WHERE manufacturer = '" . $option . "' ORDER BY diam";<br>
```

(I added a " ' ")
and options take the following syntax:

```
    <option value="option_value">bla bla bla
```

where bla bla bla is the name

Answer (score 0):

options shouldn't have name attributes; this might be the sole reason your post values break - especially since the option name is the same as the selects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with **$featuredsql**.
Display your query **$featuredsql** and check that it is working fine.